# Create a dynamic procedure call statement in mysql

Tags: mysql, dynamic

if I want to call a procedure with different input in each time  input1,input2, input 3, ... and different output out1,out2,...and so on

```
proc(input1,out1) proc(input2,out2)...
```

can I made only one prepared statement inside a while loop to do that job? something like this

```
while c <= 10 DO
    SET @sql = CONCAT('call proc(input',c,',out',c')'); 
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
    set c=c+1;
end while;
```

Comment: You can only do that in another stored procedure (or function or trigger).

Comment: yes it already inside another stored procedure ...but it did not work ... ...the error i got is "Unknown column "input1" in field list

Comment: And what is not clear about the error message?